# Is there any open source project with a "Drag and Drop to unlock" component like the unlock screen of ICS?

Tags: android, android-widget, open-source, android-custom-view

I'd like to use a widget in my app like the one in the Unlock Screen of the Android ICS (4.0).
You can see what I'm talking about with this picture:

[image: Unlock Screen of ICS]

So, I'd like a component that I can drag the circle to a padlock (or something else) so I can react to this event.

I've seen one implementation in the MusiXMatch app. It appears at its screen that is shown when we unlock the device:

[image: MusiXmatch's screen]

[image: MusiXmatch's screen]

[image: MusiXmatch's screen]

[image: MusiXmatch's screen]

My question is: is there any open source project that implements this widget?

Comment: [Questions soliciting lists of recommendations are not considered a good fit for StackExchange sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AndroidViews](http://www.androidviews.net/) shows [GlowPadView](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/glowpadview-lockring/) as being what you want, presumably.